# Поиск слова в строке по букве

Tags: java, поиск, текст

Условие:

> Написать программу, которая ищет в строке, введенной пользователем, и выводит на экран слова, начинающиеся с определенной буквы. Буква вводится пользователем.

Как осуществлять ввод вывод я знаю. Дальше, насколько я понимаю, нужно посимвольно разбить слова и проверять все символы после пробела и если буква после пробела такая же, как заданная, то выводить все символы до следующего пробела. Но как это всё прописать в коде, я слабо представляю.

Comment: [String::startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данную программу я вижу вот так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Введите строку:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Введите букву:");
        String letter = scanner.next();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsCyrillic}+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String word = matcher.group();
            if(word.toLowerCase().startsWith(letter))
                System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
```

**1)** Сканируем две строки с помощью `Scanner`.
**2)** С помощью `.split()` разделяем строку на слова, которые заносятся в массив `String[] arrayString` (`.split()` возвращает массив).
**3)** С помощью for-each loop (`for (String word : arrayString)`) проверяем каждый элемент в массиве (т.к. слово может быть с заглавной букву - используем `.toLowerCase()`), начинается ли слово с буквы (`.startsWith(letter)`), которая была введена пользователем ранее.
**4)** Если такое слово найдено, то выводим его на экран.

Comment: Окей, что если не будет пробела заверенным вами?

Comment: @And По правилам любого языка мира, слова разделяются проблемами. Но если вас интересует разделения по другим знакам - то это легко делается с помощью regex

Comment: По правилам любого языка мира, строка является любым словом без пробела.

Answer (score 0):

Можно на примитивном уровне:

```
    String string = "cat bee dog cow cat dog fly";
    char firstLetter = 'c';
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    String word = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length - 1; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == ' ' && !word.equals("")) {
            if (word.toCharArray()[0] == firstLetter) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            word = "";
            continue;
        }
        word = word.concat(String.valueOf(chars[i]));
    }
```

Результат

```
cat
cow
cat
```

Возможно, из-за того, что первая буква вводится пользователем строку

```
if (word.toCharArray()[0] == firstLetter)
```

надо будет заменить на

```
if (String.valueOf(word.toCharArray()[0]).equals(firstLetter))
```

Ещё лучше, заменить её сразу на

```
if (word.startsWith(prefix)) //String prefix = "ca";  --> result: cat cat
```

Тогда будет проверяться начинается ли слово с введенной строки, не только буквы.